# Создания класса для работы со списком

Tags: c++

> Задание: создать класс - двухсвязный список, создать конструктор,
>   деструктор. Методы работы с списком: добавление, удаление элементов,
>   сортировка списка, поиск в нем.

Набросал небольшую структуру класса, с C++ практически не знаком, возможно есть более правильный способ реализации.

Будет ли верно вводить данные прямо в конструкторе? Или для этого нужно создавать приватный метод и уже его вызывать?

```
struct tList
{
    int key;
    tList * prev;
    tList * next;
};
    class List
    {
        private:
            tList * beginList;
            tList * endList;

        tList* getElement(void){
            //выделение памяти
            //заполнение данных в структуре
        }

        public:
            List(){
                //ввод данных в список
                //вызов addElement
            }

            void addElementEnd(){
                //вызов getElement
                //добавление элемента в конец списка
            }

            void addElementBegin(){
                //вызов getElement
                //добавление элемента в начало списка
            }

            void deleteElement(tList * element){
                // удаление элемента
            }

            void sortAsc(){
                // по возростанию
            }

            void sortDesc(){
                // по убыванию
            }

            tList* searchElement(int key){
                //поиск элемента
            }

            void printList(){
                //печать списка
            }

            ~List(){
                //освобождение памяти
            }
        };
```

Comment: Поясните о каком вводе идет речь? В конструкторе у вас никаких данных не вводится.

Comment: Я имел ввиду указание количества элементов списка и последующий вызов addElement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала лучше сделать структуру `tList` внутренней структурой класса `List`, так как она относится к деталям реализации списка.

Класс должен иметь конструктор по умолчанию, чтобы можно было создавать пустой список.

Можно также создать конструктор, который принимает список инициализации `std::initializer_list<int>`, и сразу же формирует список из элементов этого списка инициализации. В этом случае вы можете в теле конструктора использовать как открытую функцию `addElementEnd`, которая добавляет элементы в конец списка, так и отдельно написанную закрытую функцию класса, если ее написание будет оправданно ее большей эффективностью по сравнению с открытой функцией класса.

Что касается указания массива и его длины в качестве параметров для конструктора, то это на ваше усмотрение. В общем случае пользователи сами поэлементно в цикле могут добавлять новые элементы в уже созданный список. С таким же успехом они могли бы добавлять в список элементы из любого другого контейнера. Не писать же для каждого такого контейнера, который служит источником элементов для списка отдельный конструктор списка?

В стандарте C++ для стандартных контейнеров такой конструктор определен. Это конструктор, принимающий два итератора (третий параметр имеет аргумент по умолчанию). Но это шаблонный конструктор. Вот как он выглядит

```
template <class InputIterator> 
list(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

Если вы не хотите связываться с шаблонами, то можете написать аналогичный конструктор, который принимает два указателя: на начало массива и на место после последнего элемента массива. То есть это будет выглядеть как специализация стандартного шаблонного конструктора для конкретных итераторов, имеющих тип `const int *`.

```
List( const int *first, const int *last );
```

или можно как вы первоначально указали

```
List( const int a[], size_t n );
```

Во всех остальных случаях, помимо копирования списков, это пользователь класса, кто должен добавлять новые элементы в класс, используя открытый интерфейс класса.

Answer (score 1):

Да конечно можно и даже нужно создавать столько конструкторов сколько предполагает сценарий использования объектов класса. Если только ваш список не несет какой-то специальной функции.

Вообще же, при реализации каких-либо контейнеров, рекомендую вам, руководствоваться прежде всего проектными решениями из стандартной библиотеки шаблонов STL.

Еще, как оффтоп, `getElement` не удачное название, лучше назвать `createElement` или `makeElement`. Просто `get` предполагает получение доступа к уже существующему объекту.